# filter: logs.blockNumber = undefined

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, filters

I have the following code:

```
var filter = web3.eth.filter({
    fromBlock:4076955, 
    toBlock:"latest",
    address:"0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
});

filter.get(function(error,logs){
  if (!error) {
    console.log("Found block " + logs.blockNumber);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(logs,null,2));
  }
}
```

and when I run the code, I get:

```
Found block undefined
[]
```

I would have expected to get a number for `logs.blockNumber` and an object as the return value (**source:** https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#watch-callback-return-value)

**Question:** Why might I not be getting the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the issue is because `filter.get()` returns logs data, only if `web3.eth.filter` is initialized before the transactions you are looking are appeared.

More info [in this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/332).

Comment: oh you mean only if the transactions haven't been added to the blockchain yet? Also if I change the `toBlock: 'latest'` to `toBlock: 4076956` I get the same result.

Comment: yes, it's not clear from docs, but, seems, you can listen only that transactions which were born after you set filter with `web3.eth.filter`

Comment: hmmm, but I was told that `filter.watch` was for listening, while `filter.get` was for getting from blocks. Here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21694/using-web3-eth-filter

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the results passed to the callback for `filter.get` are an array of entries.  I can't find any code samples from where I've done this before, but I'm pretty sure `logs` in your callback is an array of blocks or logs, not just a single one.  Try just passing `console.log.bind(console)` to `filter.get`, to see what the raw values are?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! Where in the code should I include the `console.log.bind(console)`?

Comment: Instead of `filter.get(function...)`, do `filter.get(console.log.bind(console))`